# Why are my new rim brakes worn so much?

Tags: brakes

[image]

Got these on 17 days ago and probably done no more than 60 miles. The main commute is 6 miles. 4 of that is a steep downhill.

[image]

Comment: You should show and check how you mount those on your bike. Didn't they rub all the time? Weren't you breaking with just one pad?

Comment: They weren't rubbing no had good clearance either side

Comment: Sorry I should explain one is a spare

Comment: Yeah why the heck is it happening at the rate it is the two pics show what the spare one looks like and the worn one after 17days

Comment: They could well be fake products. Trying to imitate Kool-Stop.

Comment: Do you brake continuously on a downhill or something  similar?

Comment: Are these pads from the rear or front brake? are you dragging the rear brake on the descent?

Comment: You say "new rim brakes", but you don't say "new rims".  What is the condition of the rims?  But if you do in fact run some steep downhills then the wear may not be excessive (though you might do better with a different type of pad that is "harder" to wear more slowly -- at the expense of braking power).

Comment: I had lots of initial brake pad wear with new ceramic coated DT Swiss Oxic rims (to the point where the front brake was covered in blue rubber dust). Surprisingly after ~10Mm they are still going strong.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the design of the brake pads, this appears to be a cheap generic pad that is then re-branded (in different colours) by various manufacturers.

Reviews seem to be mixed, with reports of the pad wearing quickly, but other reports of the pad lasting forever and wearing the rims out quickly.

I'd suggest that when it comes to brake pads, this is an area not to look for cheap replacements.  Either use the brake manufacturers own pads, or ones from well respected third parties such as SwissStop or Kool Stop.

Comment: Thanks Ive ordered some kool stops

Comment: Kool Stop Supra 2 Bicycle Brake Shoes (Threaded, Salmon) https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000BMT2GU/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_I5-vEbDYTMQJ0

Answer (score 3):

Check that they aren't pads for carbon wheels. Those will wear quite a bit more quickly if you are using them on aluminum.

Comment: Good thought - the carbon pads tend to be green or yellow, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it wasn't quite aligned with the wheel. In the image it looks like the end on the right is warn almost all the way through while the end on the left still has a lot of padding left. 
Pads can wear out more quickly when they don't make even contact with the braking surface.